# How will and when will Mobile browsers start serving AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) Content?

Tags: google-chrome, mobile-safari, amp-html

So Google announced Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP)
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml

Wordpress released a plugin and other publishers released some support...
but basically most publishers/websites will have an alternate set of URLs for AMP content.

I don't see it that many websites will switch their entire frontends to AMP anytime soon, so how does the mobile web take advantage of the new AMP content?

So when or how will mobile browsers decide to show this AMP content? If its in the HTML `<head>` section then the mobile browser will only know the location of the AMP content after it downloads that part. Will there be a spec for sending the AMP url in the HTTP header? Or is there another way?

Comment: Do you have a link for the wordpress plugin?

Comment: @RobCarroll https://github.com/Automattic/amp-wp/

Answer (score 7):

Websites shouldn't switch their entire frontends to AMP. AMP should be used to accelerate static, article-based content when requested by the client.

In order to inform clients that an AMP version of the content is available you can use a `link` tag in the document's `head` like:

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/amp/34471849">
```

Comment: Why not eventually once the spec matures? If it will make pages much smaller and load only what is necessary, its not a bad pattern to follow.

Comment: AMP optimises article content; it doesn't allow for external JavaScript, forms, custom fonts (other than from approved domains) and lots of other restrictions. If your site is a simple blog (that doesn't need search) then it might be beneficial to go 100% AMP, but I'd think very carefully about the implications first - most website are more than just repositories for article content

Comment: The deciding factor will be ad engagement,  while for reasons pointed out above a site is unlikely to go 100% AMP for thinks like home and navigation pages it would make sense to switch all articles over if the reduced abandonment rate yields a better page depth and ecpm.

Answer (score 1):

When Google or another app indexes the page it becomes aware that there is an AMP version. The cached version of that AMP page will be served up when a user navigates to the page via a link or within a carousel of stories.

Comment: And it would be advisable to do something like this: <meta property = "og: url" content = "http://example.com/article/example.amp" />?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start viewing AMP versions now I've released a Chrome plugin which redirects you to the AMP version if it exists.  Preferences are configurable per URL, per domain and there is a configurable default.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amp-accelerated-mobile-pa/baodpdnidmedcpanneabeldenamaaeoe

Answer (score 0):

According to this announcement: https://amphtml.wordpress.com/2015/12/09/continued-momentum-for-the-amp-project/amp/ "Google will begin sending traffic to AMP pages in Google Search as early as late February, 2016. Twitter will begin to experiment with linking to AMP content provided by publishers early in 2016."

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to distinguish on the based on **HTTP response headers** b/w normal web contents and AMP web contents.

Only after receiving web contents  there can be differentiated like AMP web contents have **"a top-level <  html ⚡> tag   or  < html amp > tag "** .

It's not possible for same contents to move to get AMP functionalities but they can keep separate AMP HTML in server.